# AIR Stage3D- confining GPU filter effects to portion of stage

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gpu, stage3d

Using [this library](https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage) to create filter effects in an application. The problem I am having is that the effects are applied to the ENTIRE stage, instead of just a portion.

Does anyone know of a way to define a 'window' or 'viewport' on a Stage3D layer? I checked the documentation for Stage3D but nothing seems exposed that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height in the configureBackBuffer method of Context3D and the x and y in the Stage3D instance:

```
stage3D.x = stage3D.y = 0;
context3D.configureBackBuffer(width, height, antiAlias, enableDepthAndStencil);
```

In the lib you're using the width and height is set to match stageWidth/stageHeight. Link to the specific line of code:

https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage/blob/12d32dab0e479620fd6420dc3fa7fcfe726502d2/examples/GPUImageShowcase.as#L120

```
stageW = stage.stageWidth;
stageH = stage.stageHeight;

// Setup context
var stage3D:Stage3D = stage.stage3Ds[0];
stage3D.removeEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);
context3D = stage3D.context3D;
context3D.configureBackBuffer(
     stageW,
     stageH,
     antiAlias,
     enableDepthAndStencil
);
```

Comment: you'd think that was it, but I tried hardcoding values to 100,100 and the filter effects still apply to the entire stage!

Comment: Maybe try playing with the fillMode and the values in GPUImage.init. There must be some scaling or resizing or something going on!